# Javascript - Calculate date 1 year/3 months/1 month ago from current date (dd-mm-yyyy)

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have a dropdown box that contains 3 options..monthly, quarterly and yearly. I am trying to populate 2 fields when either of the options are selected. The start date will be the current date, and I want to work out the end date depending on the option selected. So far I have this.

HTML:

```
<select name="date_range" class="date_range">
    <option value="None">Please select a date range</option>
    <option value="Yearly">Yearly</option>
    <option value="Quarterly">Quarterly</option>
    <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
</select>

<p>Start Date</p>
    <input type="text" name="start_date" id="start_date" />
<p>End Date</p>
    <input type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date" />
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $('.date_range').change(function(){
    var date = new Date();
    console.log(date);
    });
});
```

The console.log gives me the following:

```
Wed May 01 2013 19:42:42 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

Both the 'start_date' and end_date' fields use datepicker and currently have a format of dd-mm-yyyy. How would I calculate the correct date range (month, quarterly or yearly) from the current date to the correct format and set the value of the both fields (with the 'dd-mm-yyyy' format).

I have come across Moment.js and datejs which I may look into using if the problem is too complicated. Cheers for any help in advance.

Comment: moment.js is great for date parsing, and only 5kb minified.

Comment: added JS solution hope it helps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/XcN45/2/)

This takes advantage of the function: [`setFullYear()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setfullyear.asp) on the date object.

***Note**: I agree that changing the value to the number of months you want to change it to is the best solution because it would allow for more dynamic code.  Also my code doesn't handle None selection because I don't know what you want it to do.*

---

**HTML:**

```
<select name="date_range" class="date_range">
    <option value="None">Please select a date range</option>
    <option value="Yearly">Yearly</option>
    <option value="Quarterly">Quarterly</option>
    <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
</select>

<p>Start Date</p>
    <input type="text" name="start_date" id="start_date" />
<p>End Date</p>
    <input type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date" />
```

**JS:**

```
$('.date_range').change(function(){
    var now = new Date();
    var start = new Date();
    switch($('.date_range').find(":selected").text())
    {
        case 'Yearly':
            start.setFullYear(start.getFullYear()-1);
            break;
        case 'Quarterly':
            start.setFullYear(start.getFullYear(), start.getMonth()-3);
            break;
        case 'Monthly':
            start.setFullYear(start.getFullYear(), start.getMonth()-1);
            break;
    }
     $('#start_date').val(start.toLocaleDateString());
     $('#end_date').val(now.toLocaleDateString());
});
```

---

### If you are willing to change the HTML [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/XcN45/3/)

**HTML:**

```
<select name="date_range" class="date_range">
    <option value="0">Please select a date range</option>
    <option value="12">Yearly</option>
    <option value="3">Quarterly</option>
    <option value="1">Monthly</option>
</select>

<p>Start Date</p>
    <input type="text" name="start_date" id="start_date" />
<p>End Date</p>
    <input type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date" />
```

**JS:**

```
$('.date_range').change(function(){
    var now = new Date();
    var start = new Date();

    start.setFullYear(start.getFullYear(), start.getMonth()-$('.date_range').find(":selected").val());

     $('#start_date').val(start.toLocaleDateString());
     $('#end_date').val(now.toLocaleDateString());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `getFullYear()`?

```
var d = new Date(2013, 5, 1);
d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() - 1);
```

Comment: Although if the current date is February 29, your resulting date obviously won't be.

Comment: he isn't doing current date just a static date. var date = new Date(); is current date, i think he was just providing proof of concept that the right choice here is getFullYear for changing the year, however I'd recommend the usage of the setFullYear function.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend a slight change in HTML, using number of months instead of strings:

```
<select name="date_range" class="date_range">
    <option value="0">Please select a date range</option>
    <option value="12">Yearly</option>
    <option value="3">Quarterly</option>
    <option value="1">Monthly</option>
</select>

<p>Start Date</p>
    <input type="date" name="start_date" id="start_date" />
<p>End Date</p>
    <input type="date" name="end_date" id="end_date" />
```

Now your code is relatively simple. [Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VH5xt/). Needs a relatively modern browser that supports `<input type="date">` (on older browser will work if date is entered as `yyyy-mm-dd`)

```
$('#start_date').change(function() {
    var end_date_value = new Date($('#start_date').val()); // Start with start_date value
    end_date_value.setMonth(end_date_value.getMonth() + $('select.date_range option:selected').val()); // Add range months
    $('#end_date').val(end_date_value.toISOString().substring(0, 10));
});

$('#end_date').change(function() {
    var start_date_value = new Date($('#end_date').val()); // Start with end_date value
    start_date_value.setMonth(start_date_value.getMonth() - $('select.date_range option:selected').val()); // Substract range months
    $('#start_date').val(start_date_value.toISOString().substring(0, 10));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For the date format, use the built-in "format" method in the jquery.datepicker object:
$("#start_date").datepicker.formatDate("dd-mm-yyyy", new Date())